# css and combating text align

Tags: css

the links below the copy that i have on this tab look poor, how can i combat this

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing-page-for-pets/142212209151821?v=app_7146470109

its a css issue, best way round this?

Comment: What't the issue? Everything looks fine from here... There could be bigger margins/padding used for the product description but otherwise it's fine...

Comment: It would help to see the code. It looks like you need text-align: left; on your headings.

Comment: the problem is the spacing of the links below the product information, i would like neater links instead of the big spaces that css has imposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text-align there is set to justify, it is fine for the paragraph, but not for the links.
add a css rule to the links, and set it to left, right or center.

use firebug with firefox to debug such problems.